# How to use mouse click to open directory, file, or menu item in Midnight Commander?

Tags: mac, console, click

I cannot click anything in Midnight Commander now. If I do it - it selects some area only.

Comment: Have you tried to double click?

Comment: yes, it selects the word then

Comment: Try alter the settings in `System Preferences > Keyboard & Mouse > Mouse`

Comment: there are no any similar options (I have Lion OS). Mouse settings exist but there are no any click options

Comment: What Mac do you have?

Comment: mac air 2012 lion version

Comment: Try `System Preferences > Trackpad > Point & Click > Secondary Click`

Comment: it already checked. This works for other application - not for mc

Comment: Then I don't know

Comment: Midnight Commander runs in Terminal, doesn't it? Did clicking ever work?

Comment: I run it from terminal and clicking didn't work at all here. I suppose it depends on terminal settings, but I cannot find this option there

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does OS X's terminal app support mouse?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/does-os-xs-terminal-app-support-mouse)

Comment: If they are duplicates, we should close the newer against this. @Anthony What do you think about the answer on the other question? Does it cover your use case entirely?